# What can blow out my laptop in tail recursion function?

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

I need to make function that group list into two lists by odd and even numbers of index, start from 1, not 0. I have a problem with infinity recursion, as I think, because time of doing second function is too much and my laptop is going to take the mars.

First function with simple recursion works fine, but the second, merge2, with tail recursion is blowing out my computer.

Here is the code:

```
// Simple recursion
def merge1(listA: List[String], listB: List[String]): List[String] = (listA, listB) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => Nil
  case (head1 :: tail1, Nil) => head1 :: merge1(tail1, Nil)
  case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => head2 :: merge1(Nil, tail2)
  case (head1 :: tail1, head2 :: tail2) => head1 + head2 :: merge1(tail1, tail2)
}

merge1 (List("a", "b", "c", "d"), List("e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"));

// Tail recursion
def merge2 (listA1: List[String], listB1: List[String]): List[String] = {
  def merge2Helper(listA: List[String], listB: List[String], listACC: List[String]): List[String] =
(listA, listB) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => listACC
      case (head1 :: tail1, Nil) => merge2Helper(tail1, listB, listACC ::: List(head1))
      case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail2, listB, listACC ::: List(head2))
      case (head1 :: tail1, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail1, tail2, listACC ::: List(head1 + head2))
}
  merge2Helper(listA1, listB1, Nil)
}

merge2 (List("a", "b", "c", "d"), List("e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"));
```

Comment: Use `@annotation.tailrec`

Comment: Shouldn't the third case be:  `case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(listA, tail2, listACC ::: List(head2))` ?

Comment: shouldn't the third pattern matching case `case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail2, listB, listACC ::: List(head2))` be  `case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(listA, tail2, listACC ::: List(head2))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd case is wrong, it is passing the same list again that has just been processed.

It should be like this:

```
@tailrec def merge2Helper(listA: List[String], listB: List[String], listACC: List[String]): List[String] =
(listA, listB) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => listACC
      case (head1 :: tail1, Nil) => merge2Helper(tail1, listB, listACC ::: List(head1))
      case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(listA, tail2, listACC ::: List(head2))
      case (head1 :: tail1, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail1, tail2, listACC ::: List(head1 + head2))
}
```

You should also add the `@tailrec` annotation to hint the compiler you expect the function to be tail recursive (and fail if it is not), to ensure you don't end up in a stack overflow with long lists.

Comment: That's not what `@tailrec` does. It only tells the compiler to fail if the recursion is **not** tail recursive. If it **is** tail recursive then it has no effect.